# Password generator

Tags: php, html, security

I am playing around with CSS/HTML/PHP and created a password generator:

```
<?php

$lowercase_characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$uppercase_characters = strtoupper($lowercase_characters);
$numbers = "0123456789";
$symbols = ".-+=_,!@$#*%<>[]{}";
$chars = "";
$password ="";

function generatePassword($length, $chars){

    $charsArray = str_split($chars);

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        shuffle($charsArray);
        $password .= $charsArray[0];

    }

    echo '<div class="content-wrapper"><div class="result-content">Your generated password is:<br /><br /><input type="text" value="' .  $password . '" onclick="select()" readonly="true"></div></div>';

}

if(isset($_POST['generate_password'])){

    if(isset($_POST['symbols'])){
        $chars .= $symbols;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['numbers'])){
        $chars .= $numbers;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['lowercase_characters'])){
        $chars .= $lowercase_characters;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['uppercase_characters'])){
        $chars .= $uppercase_characters;
    }

    generatePassword(htmlspecialchars($_POST['p_length']), $chars);

}

?>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-header">
            Password Generator
        </div>

        <form method="post">
            <table class="index-table">
                <tr>
                    <td width="30%">Password Lenght:</td>
                    <td width="70%"><input type="number" name="p_length" value="15" required /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Include Symbols:</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="symbols" checked /> (e.g. @#$%)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Include Numbers:</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="numbers" checked /> (e.g. 123456)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Include Lowercase Characters:</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="lowercase_characters" checked /> (e.g. abcdefg)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Include Uppercase Characters:</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="uppercase_characters" checked /> (e.g. ABCDEFG)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Generate Password" name="generate_password" class="generate-button" style="border: none;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

It would be great if I could get some feedback on the code that I wrote, how to improve it and if there are any safety issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code, in general, is neat, practical, and generally pleasant.

#### Security

From a security perspective, it is common for passwords to **require** some character types, but in your code, these are just suggestions. It is quite possible for your code to generate the password "password". For all the password generators I have used, when you check the "special characters" check box, it guarantees there will be special character... yours does not.

#### Single Responsibility

Your function `generatePassword($length, $chars) {...}` should be a true function to generate a password. Instead, it does two things, it generates the password, and it displays it.

Your code really should be:

```
echo '<div class="content-wrapper"><div class="result-content">Your generated password is:<br /><br /><input type="text" value="'
     .  generatePassword($length, $chars)
     . '" onclick="select()" readonly="true"></div></div>';
```

Note how you call the function from inside the presentation code, and the function returns the value?

#### Algorithm

From an algorithm perspective, I think there's a better way to pull random characters, than what you are doing. You shuffle all the available characters, then pull the first one. It would be better to just pull a random one. Your code is:

> ```
> $charsArray = str_split($chars);
>
> for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
>     shuffle($charsArray);
>     $password .= $charsArray[0];
>
> }
> ```

I would prefer to see it as:

```
$charsArray = str_split($chars);
$lastChar = sizeof($charsArray) - 1;

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    $password .= $charsArray[rand(0, $lastChar)];
}
```

The above code saves a shuffle on each character, and the result is equally 'shuffled' from a random perspective.

Answer (score 6):

The answer of rolfl should be the accepted one. It handles nearly everything. I just want to add some remarks:

## Bugs

If none of the `$_POST` variables are set. Something will break...

## Security

Your password generator is **not secure**.

Shuffle internally uses the same 'randomness' as `rand()`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694538/2496717).
This means that your 'random' password is not random when talking security. It will seem random for the human eye, but a computer will quickly burst that bubble.

A much better an easier way of generating a random password is using [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php).